# Append ListItem to end, KnockoutJs template binding

Tags: knockout.js

In the following fiddle
I wish **gokul** list item to be on the top.

Without modifying the DOM if possible

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gokuldahal/xrnecuve/1/)

```
    <div id="test">
    <li>gokul</li>
</div>
<script id="someTemplate" type="text/html">
    < li data - bind = "text: name" > < span class = "remove"
    data - bind = "text :name" > Remove from < /span></li >
</script>

var data = [{
    name: "one"
}, {
    name: "two"
}];

ko.applyBindingsToNode(document.getElementById("test"), {
    template: {
        name: 'someTemplate',
        foreach: data
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/gokuldahal/xrnecuve/1/

i want the list item "gokul" on the top of ul.

Comment: Do you want to necessarily use template? Or any other way is acceptable?

Comment: i need to use template. Since the <ul> that i am referring for this template to is not in DOM, its being created on the fly and it has few list items already into it.
Now i am appending few more list items to this <UL> through this template and applying knockout bindings.

Comment: do the objects really need to be bound to the dom? could you just use jquery to append new elements to the list?

Comment: no i can't use jquery. since these list items are shown is multiple sections in dom, so if any of this listitem is removed or added, all the references should be updated in the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible under Knockout, and to make matters worse the JSFiddle you linked to is using Knockout 2.0.0.  In later versions all content of the node bound when using a template will be cleared - you will lose the "gokul" element when it is bound.

You need to use a virtual template/foreach binding that is inserted AFTER your existing LI. This can be done dynamically if you cannot modify the HTML being delivered.

With your existing HTML...

```
var data = [ { name: "one" }, { name: "two" } ];

var element = document.getElementById("test");
var startForEach = document.createComment("ko template: {name: 'someTemplate', foreach: $data }");
var endForEach = document.createComment("/ko");

element.appendChild(startForEach);
element.appendChild(endForEach);

ko.applyBindings(data, document.getElementById("test"));
```

Comment: Now to this list item, i need to add a class based on some javascript logic.
Eg elementArray1=[100, 200, 300], elementArra21=[500, 800, 800]
ElementSearch= some Random Numer

If this random number is in eiter of this two elementArray, we need to add class "activated" to the list item.